# how to update many file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

this is my controller:

```
public function ubah_pameran_belanda()
{
      $id=$this->input->post('id');
      $nama_kegiatan=$this->input->post('nama_kegiatan');
      $file1=$this->input->post('file1');
      $file2=$this->input->post('file2');
      $file3=$this->input->post('file3');
      $file4=$this->input->post('file4');
      $file5=$this->input->post('file5');
      $tanggal=$this->input->post('tanggal');
      $this->Info_pameran_belanda_model->ubahInfoPameranBelanda($id,$nama_kegiatan,$file1,$file2,$file3,$file4,$file5,$tanggal);
      redirect('belanda/pameran_belanda');
  }
```

this is my model:

```
function ubahInfoPameranBelanda($id,$nama_kegiatan,$file1,$file2,$file3,$file4,$file5,$tanggal){
    $update=$this->db->query("UPDATE pameran_belanda SET id='$id', nama_kegiatan='$nama_kegiatan', file1='$file1', file2='$file2', file3='$file3', file4='$file4', file5='$file5' , tanggal='$tanggal' WHERE id='$id'");
    return $update;
}
```

i have 5 files in database, when i update 2 files why 3 of them is missing. how can files that are not modified are not replaced by blank files?

Comment: Check if `$fileX` is not empty and add fileX to query or not.

Comment: How to write it into code ? can u write it down please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simplest solution is to check whether your variable empty or not and add it to `update` query:

```
function ubahInfoPameranBelanda($id,$nama_kegiatan,$file1,$file2,$file3,$file4,$file5,$tanggal){
    $sql = "UPDATE pameran_belanda SET id='$id', nama_kegiatan='$nama_kegiatan',";
    if ($file1) {
        $sql .= " file1='$file1',";
    }
    if ($file2) {
        $sql .= " file2='$file2',";
    }
    // etc.

    $sql .= " tanggal='$tanggal' WHERE id='$id'";

    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Alslo, as you take unsafe data from `$_POST` - beware **SQL injections**.

Comment: i got error 'Message: Use of undefined constant file1 - assumed 'file1' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)'

Comment: Make sure you use `$` where required.